# delete function on multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I have a js funciont that erase the last digit on an input, it work fine, but the problem is that i have another input and doesn't work. It just erase te digit on the first input.

```
    <script>
        function deleteTag(){
           var strng=document.getElementById('entrada_1').value;
           document.getElementById('entrada_1').value=strng.substring(0,strng.length-1);
        }
    </script>

        <form method="POST" action="dashboard.php">
            <label>RUT</label>
            <input id="entrada_1" placeholder="12345678-9" type="text" name="rut">
            <label>pass</label>
            <input id="entrada_2" placeholder="pass" type="password" name="pass">
       </form>
```

it works fine when is used on the input "entrata_1" but on "entrada_2" doesn't work, how can i make it work where the focus is?

Comment: How is this function used?

Comment: When do you call the function `deleteTag()`?

Comment: sorry forgot that, i have a button that calle it. 
<a href="javascript:deleteTag()"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xl" name="clean">&#8592</button></a>

like that

Comment: Did you mean `deleteTag` instead of `removeTextTag`? You can’t wrap a `<button>` inside an `<a>`.

Comment: It will work fine for the secondary input; you simply need to apply it to that element as well. For example, `.getElementById('entrada_2')`.

Comment: yes! sorry again jajaja

Comment: You can access the element that currently has focus by [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement).

Comment: @ObsidianAge where do i add that? i try but then it only erase on the "entrada_2" and stop working on the firstone

Comment: You kept the original code for the first one right? Assuming so, you'll need to use a different variable name. Having `var strng` for both of them will overwrite your assignment of the first one with the second one. Or just use classes for both, and then use `document.getElementsByClassName()`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge almost, if erase on both inputs but at the same time >.<, and I can't use 2 buttons :/

Comment: @Xufox I unwrapet the button from de a element, and try the activeElement, but doest work either. in fact stop working >.<

Answer (score 0):

You should instead just use a button without wrapping it in an anchor tag, give an onclick attribute like such `onclick="deleteTag();"`. Give both the input fields a class name like `class='entrada'`.

Then in the function:

```
    function deleteTag(){
       var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.entrada');
       allInputs.forEach((input) => input.value = input.value.substring(0, input.value.length - 1));
    }
```

Comment: almos >.< it works but delete from both inputs at the same time, I need that only delete from input that has te focus :/

Comment: I don't understand. If you are clicking on the button, then the focus is lost from the input and is now on the button

Comment: What i suggested deletes data from both inputs. I don't understand what exactly is your need.